# Software to draw state diagrams and asm charts?

Tags: windows, workflow, component-diagram

I would like to draw state diagrams and asm charts like these (under Win7):

[image: State Diagram]

[image: Asm chart]

Any recommendations? Can these be done with Microsoft Visio?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visio is great.  I had been using it long before Microsoft bought them.  It's really a great interface.  Expensive though.

On the free side, I would strongly suggest yEd:

[image: yEd ABOUT screen]

This is Java-based and is really an example of the Java Graph Visualization Library.  The neat thing about this  program is that it will (if you want it to) automatically arrange your diagram for you.  If you look under LAYOUT in the menu bar there are different options.  i use it when I'm done and have shapes all over the place.

Here is a yEd screenshot:

[image: yEd screenshot]

Good luck!

Comment: Looks really neat, thanks, do you think the first picture is done with Visio?

Answer (score 5):

For my graduate paper work, flow charts and even circuits were all done in Visio. It has great support for these kinds of diagrams. It's the tool all of my professors recommended for the job.

Answer (score 5):

I remember in University we used [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/) which is an "informal" version of Visio. It definitely contains many different type of charts and you can even draw some of them by hand, so will pretty sure cover your needs.

On the downside sometimes I felt the result was kind of ugly and hard to even look decent, but that's my humble opinion

Forgot to mention that Dia is free to use and open-source

Answer (score 4):

### GraphViz

If you are not afraid of *writting* your State Machines diagrams, then the best option would be to use [**`GraphViz`**](http://www.graphviz.org/).  I used it for all the diagrams in my thesis, and it worked like a charm.

> Graphviz is open source graph visualization software. Graph
>   visualization is a way of representing structural information as
>   diagrams of abstract graphs and networks. It has important
>   applications in networking, bioinformatics,  software engineering,
>   database and web design, machine learning, and in visual interfaces
>   for other technical domains.

You can see some examples of what you can achieve using GraphViz in [the GraphViz gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).

You have to write the description of the State Machine using [**`DOT`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29), which is a *Graph Description Language*. Is not difficult at all - don't let the *text* prevent you from making beautiful *graphics*. :)

Comment: So the state machine must be in DOT language, can it not realize VHDL? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Anarkie - By VHDL you mean Hardware Description Language?  I'm not sure, as for the ASM graphs I used DOT.  We will have to search in the Documentation (http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php).  Also, this link could help as an example (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-graphviz/index.html?ca=drs).  I believe that you can define your own output images, but it's been a while since I used it - I just remember that it was a great tool, and made my like a lot easier while doing my thesis :)  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Edraw](http://www.edrawsoft.com/Basic-Flowcharts.php). It has a free version which is very capable and should be mostly sufficient for the chart you're describing. It's very easy to use, but may not be as powerful as something like GraphViz.

I've used Edraw to make numerous organizational charts and flowcharts. While I'm not too familiar with state diagrams and ASM charts, my work looks very similar to what you've posted.

Here's one example image from the Edraw page:[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [LucidChart](https://www.lucidchart.com), which is actually a web-based application but it comes with a [price](https://www.lucidchart.com/users/registerLevel) although you can use the free registration and up to 25mb size for your diagrams.

Compared to `Dia` even `Visio` I think LucidChart offers the largest combination of shapes but I think are a little messed up in categories, so it requires some searching.

And also because it's web-based LucidChart is the best choice if another person or a whole team has to modify the diagram without saving file - sending file -receiving file blah blah...

Hope that helped.